# How to create a realistic water body using Matlab 3D World Editor?

Tags: matlab, 3d

I have created a 3D World comprising of a custom background and a water body in 3D World Editor. The water body is nothing but a transparent colored cylinder of large radius and height. I have attached two images showing a box floating on water, [one with viewpoint above the water surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IIZb.png) and [one with a viewpoint below the water surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms1T0.png). The problem I am facing is about the viewpoint below the water surface, as you can see in the image there is a box appearing with the custom background as if the water body is not even present there. How can I solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: Can you share source code that define the viewpoints?

Comment: These viewpoints are not defined, just panned below and above X-Z plane